# Wordpress /support/ slug emulates /blog/

Tags: wordpress, blogs, slug

I have a wordpress website that I am developing, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

I have tried to troubleshoot this prior to submitting this query. What I have tried: 
- I do not have any page, post, cpt, category, tag, plugin, etc with the slug, 'support'; 
- I have searched my database via phpMyAdmin for the term 'support', and there is NO reference to the word 'support' in the database; 
- I have looked in my .htaccess and there is no reference to 'support'; I have entered the address: mywebsite.com/support/ in multiple computers and phone browsers, in both normal mode and incognito, and the `/support/` page still shows the same information as if I typed in `/news/`.
- I have added and removed the `/news/` page in the settings as the designated blog page and the `/support/` page still thinks it's the news page.
- I have accessed permalinks via the settings page and saved it to flush the permalinks, and still nothing changes...
- I have disabled all plugins, and tried all the above, and still the same result...

In addition, I deleted the `/support/` page and the `/news/` page, and it STILL shows the /news/ page if there are posts. The only time that it doesn't show the `/news/` page, is if I delete all posts and it will return as an empty `/news/` page. If I create a new post, the `/support/` slug will show the news page again...? Simply put, it seems that the `/support/` page thinks it's the news page.

I have no idea how this could have happened. I did once have a page /support/ but it had it's own contact form in there - never did I set the /support/ page in my settings to display the news/blog page.

I understand I can obviously just change my /support/ page to /contact/ and it will not redirect, but I would prefer the slug /support/.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

UPDATE
As per your request
[image: Screenshot]

I also have query monitor installed if there is anything from that I can provide -- network response is 200. it's as if there is a page installed as /support/, but there is nothing...

CLI:

```
[support(/(.*))?/?$] => index.php?&support=$matches[2]

[(.?.+?)/support(/(.*))?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&support=$matches[3]
```

Possible issue. I think I found it... I wanted it to save account/support but its saved it as support... thoughts on how I might rectify this issue?

```
/**
 * Register Rewrite Enpoint
 * 
 * @address ../account/pets/
 * @address ../account/support/
 * 
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @access  private
 */
public function audp_create_pets_endpoint() {

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'pets', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'contacts', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'veterinary', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'support', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );

}
```

When I do domain.com/pets or /veterinary I get the same issue. I need to remove these endpoints... or make them account/support etc - if you could assist I would be grateful.

SOLUTION:

Removed EP_ROOT, and flushed permalinks.

Thanks for your assistance and for the motivation Magenta.

Comment: From your browser's network tool can you provide the exact HTTP 3XX redirect responses.

Comment: Also, can you provide the contents of your .htaccess file and the WordPress rewrite rules. The easiest way to get the WordPress rewrite rules is to use WP_CLI command - php wp-cli.phar eval 'print_r(get_option("rewrite_rules"));'

Comment: @Megenta-Cuda - Updated, please review.

Comment: So, there is no HTTP redirect so this must be done by WordPress - please provide the WordPress rewrite rules.

Comment: Updated with instances of support. How do I removed these?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Removed EP_ROOT, and flushed permalinks.

Thanks for your assistance and for the motivation Magenta.

Comment: These rewrite rules has also caused me much pain in the past.